# confused about inheritance and use of this

Tags: javascript

say I have this:

```
function something() {
    //does something here
}
something.prototype = {
    xy: function(n) {
        this.a = n;
    }
    y: function() {
        b = this.xy(n);
    }
}
```

my qusetion is, I know that in `this.a`, `this` refers to `something`. However, is `b=this.xy(n)` allowed, and if so, what would `this` in `b=this.xy(n)` refer to?

Comment: *"what would this in b=this.xy(n) refer to"* That entirely depends on *how you call* `something.prototype.y`. Please read the documentation about `this`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 1):

In `this.a`, `this` does not refer to `something`. You could *expect* it to refer to an *instance* of `something`, but `this` can be bound to anything using [`Function.prototype.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply). If you call `foo.y()` in the same way you call `foo.xy()`, though, it will refer to `foo` and that usage will be valid, yes. More than that, `this` would be the correct way to do it, to allow anything inheriting from `something` to override `xy`.

Answer (score 1):

the actual reference for "this" is not always the same and changes depending on the context and how you call the function.

for e.g
lets assume you have got a global variable "a"

```
var a;    
...
something.prototype = {
    xy: function(n) {
        this.a = n;
    }
    ...
}

var obj = new something();
obj.xy.call(this, 10); // set the context to global. this == 'global' here

console.log(obj.a); //undefined
console.log(a); //10
```

the above code calls the xy function, but sets "**this**" to the global object and modifies the global variable **a** instead of the instance variable. "this" inside the function does not refer to the object instance but the global object (window object).[call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) can be used to modify the actual meaning of "this", whenever functions are called.

```
obj.xy(10);
console.log(obj.a); // 10
```

here you are setting the context to the object instance and "this" refers to the object instance correctly and you get the expected output.

And to answer your question

***is b=this.xy(n) allowed, and if so, what would this in b=this.xy(n)***

this is allowed and the result would be again depending on the context of the call that you are making.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I assume you function is a constructor, the I create a object:

```
var obj = new something().
```

"this" keyword then refer to obj. you can do:

```
obj.y();
```

then obj.a will be set to value n. I think that's what you plan to do..

Also, your xy function doesnt have return statment,there is nothing assign to b.

Comment: Please put some structure into your answer.